# Fade-In Animation for SurfaceView not working

Tags: android, animation, surfaceview

The animation works perfectly fine for a normal View. But when I use it on a SurfaceView, then it fades out, then flashes the screen, then starts the video. The flashing looks really silly, and I need to remove that.

```
public class MyDreamService extends DreamService implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
    private SurfaceView vidSurface;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setInteractive(false);
        setFullscreen(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        vidSurface = new SurfaceView(MyDreamService.this);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(MyDreamService.this);
        frameLayout.addView(vidSurface,
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setContentView(frameLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStopped() {
        super.onDreamingStopped();
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            vidHolder = holder;
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice_activated_corgi);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        vidHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

This plays video fine, but if I want to animate:

```
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameLayout, "alpha", .3f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

    final AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();

    mAnimationSet.play(fadeIn);

    mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            if(view != null) {
                view.setAlpha(0f);
            }
        }
    });
    mAnimationSet.start();
```

Then after multiple iterations, it either fades to black, then flashes the launcher for like a second, then starts the video; or just doesn't animate at all! What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it by using an overlay view which fades to black, and once the animation ends, set the view to invisible rather than remove it.

```
public class MyDreamService extends DreamService implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
    private SurfaceView vidSurface;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setInteractive(false);
        setFullscreen(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStarted() {
        super.onDreamingStarted();
        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setContentView(frameLayout);

        vidSurface = new SurfaceView(MyDreamService.this);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(MyDreamService.this);
        frameLayout.addView(vidSurface,
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        view = new View(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        frameLayout.addView(view);


        ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameLayout, "alpha", .3f, 1f);
        fadeIn.setDuration(2000);

        final AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();

        mAnimationSet.play(fadeIn);

        mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                if(view != null) {
                    view.setAlpha(0f);
                }
            }
        });
        mAnimationSet.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDreamingStopped() {
        super.onDreamingStopped();

        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyDreamService.this, R.raw.voice_activated_corgi);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MyDreamService.this);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        vidHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }
}
```